# how can i call a script with another script and pass variables

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a application that is retrieving password from another application and it stores in a variable called `PWM_PASSWORD` which I can't see its content.

So I would like to pass this variable into script via another script

So I am running `script1` to run `script2` with a variable and the user name as below. Username is hardcoded.

`script1.ksh`:

```
ksh /opt/script2.ksh username "$PWM_PASSWORD"
```

It seems like password is not passing into the `script2` .

edit : content of the 2nd script is;
It is a very long scrip that gets the username and the password writes into another file while encrypting the password that it is received

I normally would run script to as /> ksh script2.ksh username password ( password and username would be hardcoded. however we are now using an application to retrieve password which is stored $PWM_PASSWORD . and this application needs to run script2 with password and username however it cant so i created the script 1 to run script 2 with the arguments

Any ideas?

content of script2

```
#!/bin/ksh
################################################################################                                                                                                                        ###
#
# Program     : set_password_in_passfile.ksh
#
# Parameters  : First argument is the name of the 'key'' containing the password                                                                                                                        .
#               Second argument is the username to be used with the key.
#               Third argument is the tns to be used with the key.
#               Forth argument is the password you want to set for the key.
#
# Purpose     : This script will set an encrypted password in the ${APPHOME}/etc                                                                                                                        /.passfile file.
#
# Working     : Add or update the password for a key:
#
#               Example:
#               Set the password 'key' ops$best:
#               Usage  : ./set_password_in_passfile.sh KEY account tns password
#               So e.g.: ./set_password_in_passfile.sh ops\$best ops\$best dbst1                                                                                                                        _dcs <password>
#
#               Output:
#               ./set_password_in_passfile.sh KEY account tns password
#               Could not find a key named OPS$BEST.
#               Creating key OPS$BEST.
#
#               Show what's done:
#               cat ${APPHOME}/etc/.passfile
#               OPS$BEST:OPS$BEST:DBST1_DCS:U2FsdGVkX19jI2Ma1oLlDHe8yxh+gmmkjDZL                                                                                                                        pizzQ1E=
#
#               The following function(s) will allow you to retrieve the passwor                                                                                                                        d again (script: BSTLIB.sh):
#               ...
#               BSTLIB_get_username_tnsname_password ()
#               {
#                  # Set the location to the .passfile file
#                  PASSFILE=${APPHOME}/etc/.passfile
#
#                  # Check mode on password file. Remark: RHEL adds a '.' at the                                                                                                                         end
#                  file_mode=`ls -l ${PASSFILE} | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c-10`
#                  if [ ! "${file_mode}" = "-rw-r-----" ]
#                  then
#                    echo "ERROR: Permissions on file ${PASSFILE} are not correc                                                                                                                        t! Mode must be 640." 1>&2
#                    exit 1
#                  fi
#
#                  typeset -u USERKEY
#                  USERKEY=${1}
#
#                  # Get the linenumber containing the provided key
#                  LINENUMBER_PASSFILE=$(grep -n ^${USERKEY} ${PASSFILE} | awk -                                                                                                                        F ":" '{print $1}' 2>/dev/null)
#
#                  if [ -z "${LINENUMBER_PASSFILE}" ];
#                  then
#                     echo "ERROR: Key not found in password file! (KEY: ${USERK                                                                                                                        EY})" 1>&2
#                     exit 1
#                  fi
#
#                  USERNAME=$(cat ${PASSFILE} | grep ^${USERKEY} | awk -F : '{pr                                                                                                                        int $2}')
#                  TNSNAME=$(cat ${PASSFILE} | grep ^${USERKEY} | awk -F : '{pri                                                                                                                        nt $3}')
#                  ENCKEY=GPCDatZoutRaaktNooitEensOp54123
#                  PASSWORD=$(cat ${PASSFILE} | grep ^${USERKEY} | awk -F : '{pr                                                                                                                        int $4}' | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -k "${ENCKEY}")
#
#                  if [ $? -ne 0 ];
#                  then
#                     echo "ERROR: Decrypting password failed! (KEY: ${USERKEY})                                                                                                                        " 1>&2
#                     exit 1
#                  elif [ -z "${USERNAME}" -o -z "${TNSNAME}" -o -z "${PASSWORD}                                                                                                                        " ];
#                  then
#                     echo "ERROR: username, tnsname and password could not be r                                                                                                                        etrieved! (KEY: ${USERKEY})" 1>&2
#                     exit 1
#                  fi
#
#                  echo ${USERNAME}/${PASSWORD}@${TNSNAME}
#                  exit 0
#               }
#               ...
#               BSTLIB_get_connectstring ()
#               {
#                  # Get username tnsname password
#                  CONNECTSTRING=`BSTLIB_get_username_tnsname_password ${1:-bst_                                                                                                                        exec}`
#                  STATUS=$?
#
#                  # Set connectstring
#                  if [ ${STATUS} -ne 0 ]
#                  then
#                     CONNECTSTRING=
#                  fi
#
#                  echo ${CONNECTSTRING}
#                  exit ${STATUS}
#               }
#               ...
#
#               Make sure the ENCKEY variable is set to the same string in this                                                                                                                         script and
#               in the script which must retrieve the password.
#
################################################################################                                                                                                                        ###
#
# REVISION HISTORY
#
# $Revision:: 1.3       $
#
################################################################################                                                                                                                        ###
#
# Changes
#
# When       Who          What
# 20-10-2017 S. Grondman  Initial version
#
################################################################################                                                                                                                        ###

usage()
{
printf "USAGE:\n"
printf "$0 KEY account tns password\n"
printf "$0 !!! \n"
printf "$0 !!! Remind to include escape character leading to wildcards (e.g. ops                                                                                                                        \$best)\n"
printf "$0 !!! \n"
}

check_key()
{
# Get the linenumber containing the provided key
LINENUMBER_PASSFILE=$(grep -n ^${USERKEY} ${PASSFILE} | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'                                                                                                                         2>/dev/null)

if [ -z "${LINENUMBER_PASSFILE}" ];
then
   echo "Could not find a key named ${USERKEY}."
   KEYFOUND=0
else
   KEYFOUND=1
   LINENUMBER_PASSFILE=$(grep -n ^${USERKEY} ${PASSFILE} | awk -F ":" '{print $1                                                                                                                        }')
   echo "Key ${USERKEY} located on line ${LINENUMBER_PASSFILE} in passfile."
fi
}

create_key()
{
if [ "${KEYFOUND}" -eq 0 ];
then
   echo "Creating key ${USERKEY}."
   echo "${USERKEY}:${USERNAME}:${TNSNAME}:" >> "${PASSFILE}"
   LINENUMBER_PASSFILE=$(grep -n ^${USERKEY} ${PASSFILE} | awk -F ":" '{print $1                                                                                                                        }')
   echo "Key ${USERKEY} created on line ${LINENUMBER_PASSFILE} in passfile."
fi

chmod 640 "${PASSFILE}"
}

update_key()
{
# Check if a password has been provided.

# Encrypt the new password and add extra escape slashes ("\") in order to preser                                                                                                                        ve real needed slases.
# the slashed would disappear (escaped) when adding this to a variable
NEWENCPASSWORD=$(echo ${NEWPASSWORD} | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -k "${ENCKEY                                                                                                                        }"| sed 's/\\/\\\\\\/g' | sed 's/\//\\\//g')

# Set the encypted password in the .passfile
# This perl command will replace everything on the linenumber found in LINENUMBE                                                                                                                        R_PASSFILE.
# perl -p = assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
# perl -i = edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
# perl -l = enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
# perl -e = one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
# It will do the replace: s/.*./${USERKEY}:${USERNAME}:${TNSNAME}:${NEWENCPASSWO                                                                                                                        RD}/g if $. (which is current line number (or record number) of most recent file                                                                                                                        handle.) is equal to ${LINENUMBER_PASSFILE}.

# First replace $ by \$ if there is/are
USERKEY_USERNAME_TNSNAME=$(echo ${USERKEY}:${USERNAME}:${TNSNAME}: | sed 's/\$/\                                                                                                                        \\$/g')
perl -pi -e "s/.*./${USERKEY_USERNAME_TNSNAME}${NEWENCPASSWORD}/g if $. == ${LIN                                                                                                                        ENUMBER_PASSFILE}; close ARGV if eof" ${PASSFILE}

echo "Password created/updated for ${USERKEY}:${USERNAME}:${TNSNAME}"
PASSWORD=$(cat ${PASSFILE} | grep ^${USERKEY} | awk -F : '{print $4}' | openssl                                                                                                                         aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -k "${ENCKEY}")
echo "New password for ${USERKEY}:${USERNAME}:${TNSNAME} (decrypted): ${PASSWORD                                                                                                                        }"

chmod 640 "${PASSFILE}"
}

# ******************************************************************************
#                                     Main
# ******************************************************************************

# Set the user key from the first argument
typeset -u USERKEY
USERKEY=$1

if [ -z "${USERKEY}" ];
then
   echo "User key (1st argument) not provided!"
   usage
   exit 2
fi

# Set the username to be used by the user key.
typeset -u USERNAME
USERNAME=$2
if [ -z "${USERNAME}" ]
then
   echo "Please provide the username (2nd argument) for key: ${USERKEY}"
   usage
   exit 2
fi

# Set the tnsname to be used by the user key.
typeset -u TNSNAME
TNSNAME=$3
if [ -z "${TNSNAME}" ]
then
   echo "Please provide the tnsname (3rd argument) for key: ${USERKEY}"
   usage
   exit 2
fi

# Set the new password from the third argument
NEWPASSWORD=$4

if [ -z "${NEWPASSWORD}" ];
then
   echo "Empty password (4th argument) provided!"
   usage
   exit 2
fi

# If ${APPHOME}/etc doesn't exist create it
if [ ! -d "${APPHOME}/etc" ];
then
   mkdir "${APPHOME}/etc"
   chmod 750 "${APPHOME}/etc"
fi

# Set the location to the .passfile file
PASSFILE=${APPHOME}/etc/.passfile

# Set the encryption key being used
ENCKEY=GPCDatZoutRaaktNooitEensOp54123

check_key
create_key
update_key
```

Comment: What's the content of `script2.ksh`?

Comment: It is a very long scrip that gets the username and the password writes into another file while encrypting the password that it is received

Comment: But the error depends on what's inside `script2.ksh`. How do you read the `username` and `password` variables there?

Comment: does the `script2.ksh` takes only two arguments ? and the order of the input arguments also matters

Comment: @atteggiani unfortunately i am not sure what are you asking. I normally would run script to as  /> ksh script2.ksh username password ( password and username would be hardcoded. however we are now using an application to retrieve password which is stored $PWM_PASSWORD .  and this application needs to run script2 with password and usernama however it cant so i created the script 1

Comment: Yes but to understand your problem, we need the content of `script2.ksh` or the content of `$PWM_PASSWORD`. Or explain how it doesn't work. What happens when you run it? Do you expect an output? What's instead the output your get?

Comment: @atteggiani i added the content of the script on the post. i do not know content of $PWM_PASSWORD . i am not able to see it . its an enviroment variable

Comment: Based on the script you provided it seems like the `USERKEY` is the first passed argument, `USERNAME` the second, `TNSNAME` the third, and `NEWPASSWORD` the fourth. So if you call `ksh /opt/script2.ksh username "$PWM_PASSWORD"`, you will pass `username` as `USERKEY` and `"$PWM_PASSWORD"` as `USERNAME`, with `TNSNAME` and `NEWPASSWORD` being empty. What is the output you are getting if you run `ksh /opt/script2.ksh username "$PWM_PASSWORD"`? Also, the script is cropped to the right (not all the code fits in), but it might not be relevant for your problem.

Comment: @HazalAltin, you don't need to pass environment variables on the command line at all (and _shouldn't_ do so for security reasons); they're inherited by child processes automatically; and all Bourne- and POSIX-family shells (including ksh) translate environment variables to shell variables likewise automatically.

Comment: @HazalAltin, ...on modern UNIXy systems, though, command-line arguments are relatively insecure: they're exposed to anyone who runs `ps` on the whole system; whereas environment variables are only visible to the same user account and to root -- so it's much safer to pass secrets through the environment than on the command line.

Comment: (BTW, while this might not be in your control, using all-caps names for variables you control is bad form: POSIX specifies all-caps names to be used for names that reflect or modify behavior of standard-specified tools such as the shell, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are "reserved for application use" and guaranteed to not have unexpected side effects modifying behavior of POSIX-specified tools.